# Re-install OS X on iMac that's currently running Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, multi-boot, boot-camp

I've got a 27" iMac (late 2011, maybe 2012 model) which I have completely wiped and loaded with Windows 7. Works great. No problems.

Lately, I've gotten the itch to get OS X loaded back onto this machine.

I know I could go with a complete re-wipe, reload OS X and then reload Windows 7, but that's not my ideal solution.

Instead, what I'd like to do is create a partition for OS X and re-install OS X (this time with Mavericks), giving me the option to dual-boot.

Is this possible? If so, any tutorials or guides? I tried googling this, but the search terms I used didn't turn up anything that looked like an answer to me.

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see?

Answer (score 0):

Dual-booting OS X and Windows involves setting up a hybrid MBR/GPT partition scheme on your disk so that the firmware and both OSes can find everything. This is not easy (see Rod Smith's article [Hybrid MBRs: The Good, the Bad, and the So Ugly You'll Tear Your Eyes Out](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html)). In theory, it should be possible to repartition in Windows, use Rod's [GPT fdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/index.html) to set up the hybrid magic (note: make sure you have a *good* backup first), then install OS X... but in practice, I suspect the wipe-and-rebuild-from-scratch approach is actually simpler. Apple's Boot Camp Assistant can handle the hybrid trickery, but only if you're starting from a single-partition OS X setup, and adding Windows.